# Why there is a sign change when not writing in long division?

Tags: perturbation-theory

I have a question about understanding how this step
$$
\int_0^{\delta/\epsilon}\frac{du}{1+u+\epsilon^2u^3/3+O(\epsilon^4u^5)}
$$
becomes
$$
\int_0^{\delta/\epsilon}\frac{du}{1+u}\left(1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{3}\frac{u^3}{1+u}+O(\epsilon^4u^4)\right)
$$
It makes sense to me to rewrite the first equation as
$$
\int_0^{\delta/\epsilon}\frac{du}{(1+u)\left[1+\epsilon^2u^3/3(1+u)+O(\epsilon^4u^5)\right]}
$$
Why did the sign on the second term of $\left[1+\epsilon^2u^3/3(1+u)+O(\epsilon^4u^5)\right]$ becomes minus in the final result? Which identities are used? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Long division seems to bé clear

Comment: Note that $\,1/(1 + x + O(x^2)) = 1 - x + O(x^2).$